# Empirical approaches to validate observational bounds on minimum gap between least eigenvalues of $n \times n$ correlation matrix and its submatrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, random-matrices, eigenvalues, numerical-linear-algebra

> Let
>
> - $\Sigma$ be an $n \times n$ correlation matrix whose least eigenvalue is denoted by $\lambda$.
> - $\Sigma_i'$ be an $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ submatrix of $\Sigma$ obtained by eliminating the $i$-th row and $i$-th column and whose least eigenvalue is denoted by $\lambda_i'$.
>
> Find an upper bound on the gap $$\Delta := \min_{i \in \{1,\dots,n\}}(\lambda_i' - \lambda)$$

---

**Empirical Observations:**

Empirically, I am making some observations about $\Delta$:

1. $\Delta \leq $ the mean of the absolute values of all off-diagonal entries of $\Sigma$.
2. $\Delta \leq \frac{||C_{j}||}{n-1} \leq \frac{||C_{j}||_1}{n-1}$ for all $j \in \{1\dots,n\}$, where $C_j$  denotes a column vector of $\Sigma$ including all off-diagonal entries.
3. $\Delta \leq \frac{1}{n-1}$, for any $n \times n$ correlation matrix, and the maxima is achieved when all the off-diagonal entries are equal to $\frac{-1}{n-1}$.

I am unable to prove them theoretically yet (More details on theoretical results are discussed on this [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288399/bound-on-gap-between-least-eigenvalues-of-n-times-n-correlation-matrix-and-of)). Hence, I am resorting to empirical approaches that can be convincing enough to validate these observations. A trivial approach could be to check the observations on a large population (say 10^6) of randomly generated correlation matrices.  However, such a number doesn't seem to be large enough for bigger matrices. I am wondering if someone can suggest smarter methods that could be useful in this setting?